# openDS installation showing error-- you have a firewall configured check that it allows connections to port 4444

Tags: java, firewall, opends

I'm installing OpenDS-2.2.1 on Windows 7 os. At the end of the setup this message below appears.I used previously this software some problem happened so i deleted that software and reinstalling but after reinstalling i am getting the error also i deleted the software from the registry and service also.Please help

Could not connect to the server after requesting start. 
If you have a firewall configured check that it allows connections to port 4444. 
Hide Details

```
org.opends.quicksetup.util.ServerController.startServer(ServerController.java:511)
org.opends.quicksetup.util.ServerController.startServer(ServerController.java:292)
org.opends.quicksetup.installer.offline.OfflineInstaller.run(OfflineInstaller.java:142)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Where is the programming-related question?

Comment: @RealSkeptic share the link where this new user can post it actually.